# Quartz - Shutdown Scheduler based on Job Variable

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz to schedule a job in Java.
The scheduler repeats indefinitely.
If a certain exception occurs in the Job.class, I need to shutdown the scheduler.
How can I get the Job to notify the scheduling class to shutdown()?

Thanks,
RayK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz's jobs are run by calling their `execute(JobExecutionContext)` method. This `JobExecutionContext` object has a `getScheduler()` method to access the `Scheduler` that is running your job.

So you could just do:

```
class YourJob implements Job {
    //...
    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        //...
        if (someCondition) {
            try {
                context.getScheduler().shutdown();
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                // log or rethrow!
            }
        }
        //...
```

However, I'm not really sure if shutting the Scheduler down in the middle of running a job is a good idea. Why do you want to do that? If all you're trying to do is to stop some job from running again, it may be better to just [unschedule](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UnscheduleJob.html) it:

> Unscheduling a Particular Trigger of Job:
>
> ```
> // Unschedule a particular trigger from the job (a job may have more than one trigger)
> scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey("trigger1", "group1"));
> ```
>
> Deleting a Job and Unscheduling All of Its Triggers
>
> ```
> scheduler.deleteJob(jobKey("job1", "group1"));
> ```

Comment: Here's the scenario - Each morning, a set of files are sent to a folder.  My code searches this folder for the files between 3A and 7A.  If the files are found, I move them and process them.  Each time the job runs after that, no files are found (the files were moved) so nothing else gets processed.  The next morning, the process starts all over again.  The problem is when there are no files moved to that folder that day.  If at 7AM, no processing has been done, I need to shutdown the scheduler so it doesn't attempt to process the next days files.  They need to be done sequentially.

Comment: @DropOfGoldenSun Oohhhh the 3AM-7AM guy! Sorry I didn't recognize you. I'll edit my answer to address what you just said.

Comment: That's me.  I'm still trying to figure this all out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related to the same issue, once I shutdown the scheduler from the job, is there a way to notify the scheduling class, so I could stop the service?

Comment: @DropOfGoldenSun mmmmm to _shutdown_ the scheduler means to turn it off for _every_ job. The whole scheduler gets stopped and no jobs will run again unless you `start()` the `Scheduler` again. What you probably want to do is to _unschedule_ or maybe _delete_ your job and only your job; see my edit.

Comment: I don't anticipate using this scheduler for any other jobs.  Currently, I am running this test in NetBeans and when I shutdown the scheduler, the application is still running.  Once this is all done, I will run it as a Windows Service.  When the scheduler is shutdown, I would like to run System.Exit(0) to stop the Windows Service.  I'm a big proponent of cleaning up and don't want to leave it running for no reason.

Comment: @DropOfGoldenSun I see. Then maybe it'd be better to have your job spawn a different thread with the necessary logic to shutdown the scheduler and exit the program. Or add a `while(true)` loop at the end of your `main()` method, that continuously checks if the scheduler is running and exits the program when it is not. But that's material for a different question :)